# Golang exec.Command problem: always fails with exit code 2

Tags: go, command, exec

My problem:

I would like to invoke the `go build` command from golang code using the built-in exec package. With many external programs, this works just fine. But with `go build`, it doesn't quite seem to work out right.
It always just returns `exit status 2`

Edit #1: when running the command in a normal command line window or powershell window, everything works as expected.

What I tried so far:

- setting `cmd.Path` and `cmd.Dir` to the working directory
- instead of running it with `go run`, I compiled it and placed the binary in the correct working directory
- redirecting both `cmd.Stdout` and `cmd.Stderr` to a byte buffer, which turns out to be empty
- tried it with absolute instead of relative paths

---

The code:

```
parts := strings.Split(fmt.Sprintf(`go build -o %s -a -v -work -x -ldflags "-s -w" %s`, artifact, bd.CloneDir), " ")
cmd := exec.Command(parts[0], parts[1:]...)
messageCh <- fmt.Sprintf("build command to be executed: '%s'", cmd.String())
result, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
if err != nil {
    messageCh <- fmt.Sprintf("build step '%s': failed because %s", buildStep, err.Error())
    return "", err
}
messageCh <- fmt.Sprintf("build step '%s': successful with content:\n%s", buildStep, string(result))
```

---

The output:

```
build command to be executed: 'C:\Go\bin\go.exe build -o data/2/1619456424/artifact/github-public-golang-test-repo -ldflags "-s -w" data/2/1619456424/clone/main.go'
build step 'build': failed because exit status 2
```

---

I hope you have some clues for me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem is probably with Split and `"-s -w"`. It would split that as two separate args. Build the array elements one by one instead of split.

Comment: right, seems like I'm blind. This was the correct answer. Post it as answer and I'll mark it.

Comment: You should not be "setting `cmd.Path` to the working directory". [Per the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd), "Path is the path of the command to run". Using `Split` is also incorect as shell parsing isn't a simple split on spaces. As Burak noted, you should be building the args list as a slice, not by trying to use `Split` to emulate shell parsing.

Comment: I'm using a `[]string` now, but the linker flags still act up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
ldflags "-s -w"
```

When split, this will produce three args, not two, namely `ldflags`, `"-s`, and `-w"`.

Build the array elements one by one instead of split. For ldflags, use:

```
args:=[]string { "go",
  ...
 "ldflags",
 "-s -w",
  ...
}
```

Comment: Even building the command with a `[]string`, the ldflags didn't work :( without it, it works fine

Comment: See the edited answer. Did you do it like that?

Comment: I used `"-s -w",`, but surrounded by double quotes, like in the original post. I removed the quotes and it works, thanks! It appears I have to come to new conclusions...